# How to remove 0s from dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have an object called `result`. `result.f` is a dictionary in the form (as an example):

```
{('a','a'):9, ('a','b'):10, ('a','c'):0}
```

I want to remove the items that equal to 0 from the dictionary `result.f`. I wrote the following code:

```
new_f=set()
for j in result.f.keys():
    if result.f[j]!=0:
        new_f.append(j:result.f[j])
```

But I have a syntax error:

```
    new_f.append(j:result.f[j])
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I write the new dictionary in `new_f` such that `new_f` equal `result.f` after removing the items that equal 0 ?

**UPDATE:** 
If the dictionary is: 
`{('a','a'):9, ('a','b'):10, ('a','c'):0}`
I want the output to be the same as the previous but without the 0 item: 
`{('a','a'):9, ('a','b'):10}`

Comment: First, note that new_f is a set, and sets have no 'append' method.  Second, what is "j:result.f[j] supposed to mean?  What are you trying to do with the colon?

Comment: j is the key and result.f[j] is the value. So, I want to build the new dictionary as: key:value. For example: `{('a','a'):9}` because if I did not add `j:`, the resulted set will only contains the values without keys.

Comment: As to why your original attempt didn't work, `new_f` was a `set`, not a `dict`, and to add new keys you would have wanted `new_f[j] = result.f[j]`.  `.append` is only a method of `lists`.

Comment: Also, why are people downvoting?  This is a perfectly valid question asked very clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
new_f = dict((k,v) for (k,v) in result.f.iteritems() if v != 0)
```

Or written more closely to the OP's form:

```
new_f=dict()
for j in result.f.keys():
    if result.f[j]!=0:
        new_f[j] = result.f[j]
```

Comment: +1.  This is probably the shortest way to do it.  Unfortunately, items() can be very slow if there are many dictionary entries, since it essentially makes a copy of the entire dictionary in memory.

Comment: This did the job. Thanx.

Comment: In dict-comprehension `{k: v for k, v in result.iteritems() if v != 0}` (Py 2.7.x required).

Comment: @misha, You're right!  That should be iteritems() instead.  Corrected.  But then that still makes a list for dict to consume, so we need dictionary comprehensions.

Comment: `.keys()` also produces a list in Python2. Better to just use `for j in result.f:`

Comment: @gnibbler, the second block was an attempt at a minimal working repair of the OP's code, but good point.

Answer (score 3):

Using a list comprehension:

```
for key in [k for k in d if d[k] == 0]:
    d.pop(key)
```

Comment: `d.pop(k)` might be more idiomatic

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mydict = {('a','a'):9, ('a','b'):10, ('a','c'):0}
for i in filter(lambda x: mydict[x] == 0, mydict):
    del mydict[i]
print mydict
```